# Scala Play framework web application hosting Process

Tags: scala, playframework, web-hosting

I'm working in a web project using scala and play framework. I`m worried about application deployment part. I need to host my application in a Glass fish server. So anyone has experience in that? I have experience in hosting javaEE apps upload the .war file to the server. but how can I host play application like that?
i have refer following article and build the dist.
[Production Dist](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ProductionDist)

If anybody can give me the instructions step by step it easy to understand it to me. Thanks

Comment: I don`t have idea how and what should i upload to server.  I have created a zip file using this article (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ProductionDist). with that how can I host my application in a server like glassfish

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The recommended way to run Play! app in production is to run it in a standalone mode, not in a application server environment. There are plugins that can build the *.war file for you, however, if that's the way you prefer to go forward. Particularly, take a look at this one: https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin

I would still suggest that you do the recommended, standalone deployment. We have a good experience with [sbt-native-packager](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager) SBT plugin. It can build `deb` and `rpm` files, with support of System V or Upstart startup scripts. There is more information on the [Play! Production page](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Production).

To use the `sbt-native-packager`, you'll need to add it to your `project/plugins.sbt` file first. Just like this: `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.1.0-RC2")`.

Then in the `build.sbt` you'll have to configure the necessary properties of the package, as described on the `Production` page linked above. I'll copy some of the configuration from that page here. Let's say, you'll use `rpm` format to deploy on CentOS. Here's what you need to put in your `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala, RpmPlugin)

maintainer in Linux := "First Lastname <first.last@example.com>"

packageSummary in Linux := "My custom package summary"

packageDescription := "My longer package description"

rpmRelease := "1"

rpmVendor := "example.com"

rpmUrl := Some("http://github.com/example/server")

rpmLicense := Some("Apache v2")
```

Then start `sbt` from command line and execute this command: `rpm:packageBin`. It will build your app and create the `rpm` file, which will be placed and named like this: `./target/rpm/RPMS/noarch/your-application-name.noarch.rpm`.

From there, it's a standard `rpm` that you could deploy and start as usual.

Comment: Great answer. It might be a stupid question, but after you build an rpm (or any other format) and start the app, the application will run in a jvm. How do you specify the settings of the JVM (heap space, etc..)

Comment: SBT native packager plugin allows you to configure JVM parameters. Have a look here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/archetypes/java_app/customize.html