# Extract HttpServletRequest from akka-http

Tags: scala, servlets, servlet-filters, spray, akka-http

We are migrating our application from **spray** to **akka-http**. We have a requirement to fetch few attributes from `HttpServletRequest` (set by filters).

Spray has a provision to extract `HttpServletRequest` by setting `spray.servlet.servlet-request-access` to `on`, like:

```
def httpServletRequest(requestContext: RequestContext): Option[HttpServletRequest] = {
  requestContext.request.headers collect { case ServletRequestInfoHeader(hsRequest) => hsRequest } headOption
}
```

However, I couldn't find similar provision in akka-http. Is there a we can acheive this in  **akka-http**?

**Update:**
As per [AKKA-http deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987639/akka-http-deployment), **spray-servlet** is not yet ported to **akka-http**, and akka runs on embeded webserver. Where as our application runs on Tomcat, So we need to wait for sometime to use akka-http on tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> spray-servlet is not yet ported to akka-http

Don't hold your breath. The Akka team didn't port over the spray-servlet module to Akka HTTP, because servlet containers don't fill well with the [reactive](http://www.reactivemanifesto.org) approach to which Akka adheres.